# What type of screw is this?

Tags: screws

I have to replace several light units that are secured with this type of screw. I assume this is a type of tamper resistant screw. Can anyone tell me what it is called?

[image: mystery screw]

Comment: Is that actually the head of a screw, or is that the hole it would go into? If it's the hole then it looks to me like a quarter-turn kind of thing.

Comment: both Amazon and widgets.com sell, or used to, large sets of funky bits and security bits.  Shop around and you may find a (much better) photo of a bit that matches what you've got. Your photo is not very good, sadly.

Comment: @brhans Sorry about the poor photo, its the head of the screw. It's like a male clutch screw head if that's a thing

Answer (score 3):

[image: Security Screw Diagram] 
My guess is that this is a Clutch type screw. (First row, sixth column)